# Why a requested/sniffed BLE characteristic handle mismatch on Linux?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, linux

I'm learning BLE and trying to sniff packets just to understand how communication happens. I do this with Wireshark on Linux and sniff traffic between the Linux machine and a BLE-powered wristband.

I noticed that sniffed packets always have the characteristic handle +1 of what I used to send a request to. For instance, when I send a request with char handle=0x46, Wireshark shows me packets with handle=0x47. I'd like to know why this happens, thanks in advance!